# Get Facebook Username using Windows Azure

Tags: java, android, facebook, azure

Hereis my problem,

I make an Android application and i use Windows Azure.

I use Azure to make login activity with Facebook. It works well i can log in.

However i want to get the Name and last name of the guy who log in using Facebook.

I have no idea how to do it using windows azure, i check this web site http://blogs.msdn.com/b/carlosfigueira/archive/2012/10/25/getting-user-information-on-azure-mobile-services.aspx

But i don't understand it. Anyone got an idea on how to get the name and last name of the person who log in using windows azure on android ?

Answer (score 0):

To get user's information from facebook, first User must authorize it. Second, you need to query this information using graphs api from facebook.

Here some tutorials that could help you:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/carlosfigueira/archive/2012/10/25/getting-user-information-on-azure-mobile-services.aspx

http://chrisrisner.com/Authentication-with-Windows-Azure-Mobile-Services

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/getting-started/